# create a bar chart in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, bar-chart

I have a csv file whose data looks like this :

```
                A       B       C       D       E
    feature1    0.6388  0.581   0.612   0.571   0.5758
    feature2    0.6218  0.537   0.624   0.535   0.6235
    feature3    0.5639  0.404   0.56    0.497   0.569
    feature4    0.6695  0.622   0.656   0.542   0.6337
    feature5    0.6252  0.532   0.625   0.523   0.6235
    feature6    0.6712  0.584   0.641   0.52    0.632
```

where I have 6 features of 5 classes. I want to plot this as a bar chart ( x axis will have the features and y axis values from 0 to 1, and the `bars` would be of class A,B...). How do I do this without redundant coding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use pandas....

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from io import StringIO

csvfile = StringIO("""
                A       B       C       D       E
    feature1    0.6388  0.581   0.612   0.571   0.5758
    feature2    0.6218  0.537   0.624   0.535   0.6235
    feature3    0.5639  0.404   0.56    0.497   0.569
    feature4    0.6695  0.622   0.656   0.542   0.6337
    feature5    0.6252  0.532   0.625   0.523   0.6235
    feature6    0.6712  0.584   0.641   0.52    0.632""")

df=pd.read_csv(csvfile, sep='\s\s+', index_col=0)

ax = df.plot.bar()
ax.set_ylim(0,1)
ax.legend(ncol=5,loc='upper center')
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Just getting fancy for the fun of it.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from io import StringIO

csvfile = StringIO("""
                A       B       C       D       E
    feature1    0.6388  0.581   0.612   0.571   0.5758
    feature2    0.6218  0.537   0.624   0.535   0.6235
    feature3    0.5639  0.404   0.56    0.497   0.569
    feature4    0.6695  0.622   0.656   0.542   0.6337
    feature5    0.6252  0.532   0.625   0.523   0.6235
    feature6    0.6712  0.584   0.641   0.52    0.632""")

df=pd.read_csv(csvfile, sep='\s\s+', index_col=0)

ax = df.plot.bar(zorder=2)
ax.set_ylim(0,1)
ax.legend(ncol=5,loc='upper center')
ax.grid(axis='y')
ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean something like

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')

df.plot.bar()
```

Output:

[image]